# Signed 16 bit PCM transformations aren't working. Why?

Tags: java, android, audio, pcm

For the past 2 days I've been trying to manipulate 16 bit PCM data on Android with little success. I'm currently using [WAV recorder](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/AndroidWaveRecorder/src/roman10/tutorial/androidwaverecorder/WavAudioRecorder.java) to capture audio. In the `onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)` method before the buffer is written with the `randomAccessWriter` I send the buffer to a custom class, to manipulate the samples, and save the samples back into the buffer. The method in my custom class is as follows:

As the buffer is a byte array I first convert them into shorts, now one short represents a frame (there's only one channel). I will be implementing FFT algorithms, once I get past this hurdle, that need the input to be a float array - so I convert each short into a float. Now, the `randomAccessWriter` that writes the data into the WAV file accepts a byte array and is expecting each frame to be 2 bytes. Therefore I convert each float back into a short and use a ByteBuffer to reconstruct a byte array, which is then returned. When I run my recorder app, with the buffer being sent through the above code, everything is fine.

I try using a simple voice modulation algorithm to test if the recording is modified, the algorithm is placed where the TODO comment is:

Now if I used the above code on my iPhone the audio samples would be transformed, although the data is natively 32bit floats. However, on Android when I re-run the recorder app, with the above code inserted, all that's produced is white noise. Until I can successfully modify the samples with the above code, I can't proceed with my FFT algorithms.

Why is this occurring? I would be grateful if someone with knowledge on the topic could shed light on the topic.

**SOLVED - By Bjorn Roche**

Underlying cause: Recording was giving data in Little Endian whereas Java shorts are in Big Endian; when applying a function using the two different forms, white noise is produced. The below code shows how to take in a Little Endian byte array, convert to Big Endian float array and back to Little Endian byte array. Whilst floats you can do whatever you please, I'll now be using my FFT algorithms:

```
public byte[] manipulateSamples(byte[] data,
                                int samplingRate,
                                int numFrames,
                                short numChannels) {

    // Convert byte[] to short[] (16 bit) to float[] (32 bit) (End result: Big Endian)
    ShortBuffer sbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).asShortBuffer();
    short[] audioShorts = new short[sbuf.capacity()];
    sbuf.get(audioShorts);

    float[] audioFloats = new float[audioShorts.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < audioShorts.length; i++) {
        audioFloats[i] = ((float)Short.reverseBytes(audioShorts[i])/0x8000);
    }

    // Do your tasks here.

    // Convert float[] to short[] to byte[] (End result: Little Endian)
    audioShorts = new short[audioFloats.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < audioFloats.length; i++) {
        audioShorts[i] = Short.reverseBytes((short) ((audioFloats[i])*0x8000));
    }

    byte byteArray[] = new byte[audioShorts.length * 2];
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
    sbuf = buffer.asShortBuffer();
    sbuf.put(audioShorts);
    data = buffer.array();

    return data;

}
```

Comment: For a start, I'd check the pass-through scenario without any processing in the middle.  You ought to get out what you put in.   May I suggest writing some unit tests?   You might also try stepping through this with the debugger.   I'd pay particular attention to dividing a float by an integer (`(float)audioShorts[i])/0x8000`).  Can't remember the promotion rules off-hand for Java, but this looks like a plausible cause.  Try recasting this as `(float)audioShorts[i])/32768.0f`.  You might have the same issue in the other direction as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have tried without any processing in the middle and the data passes through fine, I also tried your suggestion and the noise was still present, I'm baffled as to why this is happening so as I don't know why it's happening I can't write any junit tests.

Comment: Before you try such a complex test, you should try something simple, like dividing by 2.

Comment: I have also tried that, instead of Math.sin(theta) I did *= 0.5. The result is white noise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that shorts in java are bigendian, but if you got your data from a WAV file the data is little endian.

Comment: Is there anyway I could convert them into Little Endian, do the transforming of the samples then back to Big Endian (as the RandomAccessWriter is expecting) or do I have to save the wav file, then reopen it then do what I want to do with the samples?

Comment: Wait, I just re read what you said. The data is already in Big Endian, the data is being recorded from the Mic. So therefore shouldn't I be able to do the transformation in the way I'm attempting?

Comment: I might be missing it, but looking at the code for wav recorder, I don't see any byte-swapping between recording and writing to the file. That means the endianness of the recording is the same as the file, and WAV files are little-endian, so the recording is little endian.

Comment: Why not try swapping the bytes, dividing by two, and swapping the bytes back. You'll know if it works or not.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, my confusion came from using the order() function of the ByteBuffers and using Byte.BIG_ENDIAN and Byte.LITTLE_ENDIAN but those failed. Instead I reversed the individual shorts and it worked. THANKS!!!

Comment: I have updated my question with the solution based of your help.